# Variable names are retrieved from DB

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have Oracle DB 10g, I created a setup table that includes my application functions, and each function variables.

I need to insert the variables values at runtime into a debug table, so I am defining in the first table the variables names that I need to insert them in the debug table.

For example I need to insert the value of variable called `L_sEmpSalary`.

The problem is that I am fetching the variable name from the setup table in a variable called for example `L_sVarName`.
The variable `L_sVarName` is including now the variable `L_sEmpSalary` that I want to insert it's value in DB

So I need to get a value of variable `L_sEmpSalary` which is stored in variable `L_sVarName`.

below is sample code:

```
declare
   L_sEmpSalary Number :=500; 
   Sql_Statment Varchar2(500); 
Begin 
   For Rec In GetVars Loop 
      L_sVarName:=Rec.Var_Name; 
      /* L_sVarname is Holding now variable 'L_sEmpSalary' which i need to get it's value which is 500*/ 
      Sql_Statment:= ' select :var from dual '; 
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE Sql_Statment into L_sVarValue using L_sVarName; 
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'Var value = '||L_sVarValue); 
   End Loop;
end;
```

I tried DBMS_SQL but no luck , any Idea?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Let us get this strait: the variable `L_sVarName` holds the **name** of the varibale `L_sEmpSalary` (which is 'L_sEmpSalary') and you want to build some generic function to insert `L_sEmpSalary's` **value** into the debug table, right ?

Comment: Where is the value of `L_sEmpSalary` held ?

Comment: Yes Dear, what you mentioned in the right.

Comment: L_sEmpSalary is holding the employee salary which i need to insert it in the debug table, below is sample code            

L_sEmpSalary Number :=500;

Sql_Statment Varchar2(500);

Begin

For Rec In GetVars Loop

 L_sVarName:=Rec.Var_Name;  /* L_sVarname is Holding now variable 'L_sEmpSalary' which i need to get it's value which is 500*/
 
 Sql_Statment:= ' select :var from dual ';
 
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  Sql_Statment into  L_sVarValue using L_sVarName; 
 
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'Var value = '||L_sVarValue);

 
End Loop;

Comment: 1. better to update your question and add the code sample (i did it for you this time). 2. what is the error code you get ? why isn't it working ?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what L_sVarName contains?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your problem, you cant use the `bind variable` in the select clause.
You can use concatination:

```
 execute immediate 'select ' || l_svarname || ' from dual' into l_svarvalue;
```

Of course you'll have to have the value 500 in column L_sEmpSalary in the table you query (I assume that in your real code it's not dual)

For example:

```
Sql_Statment := 'with t as (select 500 L_sEmpSalary from dual) ' ||
                'select l_sVarName || ' from t' into l_sVarValue;
```

Though I probably still don't really understand what you're trying to do...

Comment: the problem that DBMS is printing 'L_sEmpSalary'  as string not the value of variable L_sEmpSalary which is 500 which i need to print.

Comment: Well, of course it would, where do you expect it to get the `500` value from ? it's not in dual...

Comment: Take a look at the SYS.DBMS_DEBUG package.

Comment: Dear, L_sEmpSalary is intialy decalred with 500 in the above code sample.  (L_sEmpSalary Number :=500;), so I find way to print this 500 through variable L_sVarName.